# Updating a table, setting a substring using another table via Sub-Select

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring, subquery

I am currently using a query, however sometimes it doesn't update all fields. 
I need a workaround on this. Can anybody help me?

```
update table1 
set number = 
( 
select substring(number from offset) 
from table2 
where strpos(number,prefix) = '1' 
order by length(prefix) 
desc limit '1' 
) ;
```

table1:

```
number
----------
1001123456
```

table2:

```
prefix | offset
-------+-------
1001   | 5
```

My goal, hopefully, is to retrieve only the 
substring (in this example "123456" for every row in table1 
that matches the specific prefix in table2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need the `offset` field.

**Table 1:**

```
+------------+
|   NUMBER   |
+------------+
| 1001123456 |
|   10012222 |
|  200244444 |
|    2003666 |
+------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+--------+
| PREFIX |
+--------+
|   1001 |
|  20036 |
+--------+
```

**Query:**

```
select number, prefix,
  cast(
    substring(cast(t1.number as text), 
              char_length(cast(t2.prefix as text)) + 1)
  as integer) as suffix
from t1
join t2 on cast(t2.prefix as text) = 
  left(cast(t1.number as text),
       char_length(cast(t2.prefix as text)))
```

**Result:**

```
+------------+--------+--------+
|   NUMBER   | PREFIX | SUFFIX |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 1001123456 |   1001 | 123456 |
|   10012222 |   1001 |   2222 |
|    2003666 |  20036 |     66 |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Mosty! I forgot to mention I am using Postgresql 8.2.1 because we can't update it for now. Although, i'm kind of lost on the cast expressions. It is the same with the "::" correct?... Also, the left(... part seems not to be working on mine. I wonder what went wrong?

Comment: Hey John! Hmm, I don't know much about Postres (I know nothing, actually) but I'm sure that works on version 9. Take a look at this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/04bef/19). I don't know how to cast in Postgres, but cast the way you usually do :) The *left* seems to be added in version 9 and is actually the same as *substring(1, x)*, I think :) See [8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-string.html) and [9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: Moreover, I tried this: select number, prefix, substring(t1.number from length((t2.prefix)::integer + 1)) as suffix 
from t1 join t2 
on t2.prefix = substring(t1.number from 1 for char_length(t2.prefix::int + 1 ));